# Embed a terminal frame into a JFrame window Java

Tags: java, terminal

I've been trying to make an app to act as a ssh / scp client to make transferring files easier from my laptop to my desktop and currently I have been able to get the output of a ls command and get the file tree for the host and remote user, however this requires input in the terminal I am running the app with.

Is it possible to be able to embed a terminal window into a gui as I have went about making an interpreter however things like tab completion and running, for example, python3 don't work. I am also hoping to have full use of a terminal and be able to run commands like vim rather than just print the output of commands which is what I currently have.

My code for executing the commands is:

```
public void processCmd(String command) {
        if (command.equals("exit")) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (command != null && !command.isEmpty()) {
            execCommand(command);
        }
}

public void execCommand(String input) {
        String result = null;
        try {
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();                    

            Process p = r.exec(input);

            BufferedReader in =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
                result += inputLine;
            }
            in.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
}
```

The main problem is that when anything like python or vim is run, the app will hang and not do anything, python won't even show up in terminal, however, if I run vim, it will change the terminal screen (not in the app) to mostly vim but without the bottom bar.

Comment: "Is it possible to ..." yes. The answer to such a question is almost always "yes". On the other hand, the amount of effort you must put into it varies.

Comment: Do you know any examples of this being done as I cannot find any?

Comment: You haven't specified why python3 doesn't work, or posted any code, which makes this hard to answer. Always when forking and managing other processes in Java it is useful to familiarise yourself with the [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class, which can help you set up the stdin/stderr to be managed from Java.

Comment: Python will make the app hang and not show anything in the gui or terminal, however it will start a python process which can be viewed in activity monitor

Answer (score 0):

So I've been round and round with this switching between Java and Python over the last 2 years. My biggest issues on the Java side is the ssh library itself. jsch seems to be popular. I've looked a little a the apache project one as well. on The front side you could use XTerm.js (or HTerm I think is the other popular one). Writing your own terminal emulation is going to be a huge pain, I highly suggest using a framework with a webengine that has a bridge mechanism to the native code your writing in. PyQT/Pyside and JavaFX both have this. This is why you see so many electron/node.js based solutions for this. I learned a lot about the mechanics from this project: https://github.com/javaterminal/TerminalFX. It has good examples of how to handle the streams work.

That said, I did finally have success with python, using a similar approach in PyQt6. Feel free to fork, or just take a look at the approach. Managing psuedo terminals is part of the issue. This is working code for ssh specifically, but has links to my other project UglyWidgets with some windows specific functionality and a lot of examples on how to handle native code to javascript bridging as well: https://github.com/scottpeterman/UglyPTY